# Configure GRE tunnel to start on reboot?

Tags: networking, tunnel

I'm trying to configure GRE tunnel (between 2 VBOX ubuntu server 12.04 LTS on win 7 host) but it keep failed.

The configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# VBOX A
ip address 172.168.1.1 /24
ip tunnel 10.0.201.1 /24

# VBOX A
iptunnel add tunX mode gre remote 172.168.1.1 local 172.168.2.1 ttl 225
ifconfig tunX 10.0.201.1/24
ifconfig tunX up
ifconfig tunX pointopoint 10.0.201.2
ifconfig tunX multicast

# VBOX B
ip address 172.168.2.1 /24
ip tunnel 10.0.201.2 /24

seting tunnel di VBOX B
iptunnel add tunY mode gre local 172.168.2.1 remote 172.168.1.1 ttl 225
ifconfig tunY 10.0.201.2/24
ifconfig tunY up
ifconfig tunY pointopoint 10.0.201.1
ifconfig tunY multicast
```

But ifconfig shows the tunnel is up

Are there any other way to configure the GRE tunnel to start on reboot beside `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration???

Answer (score 0):

Use crontab

```
sudo crontab -e
```

instead of setting the time of minute hour

```
* * * * * `command>
```

use

```
@reboot <command>
```